# How to delete corresponding row with ManyToMany relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to make a basic pizza app with two API's, toppings and pizzas. When I delete a topping, I would like for the corresponding pizzas to also be deleted since the topping is no longer available. As it currently stands, when I delete a topping it just keeps an empty pizza object.

Models:

```
class Toppings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    topping = models.ManyToManyField(Toppings, max_length=60, related_name="toppings")

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name, self.topping)
```

Serializers:

```
class PizzaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    toppings = ToppingsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields = "__all__"
class ToppingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Toppings
        fields = "__all__"
```

Pizza.views and Toppings.views are almost the same so I just included Pizza.

```
class PizzaList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer


class PizzaCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer


class PizzaUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer


class PizzaDelete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer
```

Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ManyToMany by itself does not handle automatic deletion protocols since it does not have sense; It's designed to permit related instances on both sides.    What you could do here are various approaches to accomplish what you want, what I'd suggest is to configure a [pre_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal on your `Toppings` model that deletes all of its related `Pizzas` before being deleted. Also, I would recommend to decouple your M2M relationship and define it as a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for a cleaner approach and more granular control over your M2M data structure (but this is just my personal opinion and style).

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I am now looking at the through model. Thanks again for the advice.